# failed to open postfixadmin login page

Tags: php, postfix-mta

PHP version 7.0.19-1
Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
Checking for dependencies:

```
Magic Quotes: Disabled - OK
Depends on: presence config.inc.php - OK
Checking $CONF['configured'] - OK
Depends on: presence config.local.php - OK
Depends on: MySQL 4.1 - OK
Testing database connection (using mysqli) - OK
Depends on: session - OK
Depends on: pcre - OK
Depends on: multibyte string - OK
Depends on: IMAP functions - OK
```

Everything seems fine... attempting to create/update database structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS config (
`id` int(11) not null auto_increment primary key,
`name` VARCHAR(20) /*!40100 CHARACTER SET latin1 */ NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`value` VARCHAR(20) /*!40100 CHARACTER SET latin1 */ NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
UNIQUE name ( `name` ) ) ENGINE = MYISAM COMMENT = 'PostfixAdmin settings'
```

Updating database:

old version: 0; target version: 1835 (If the update doesn't work, run setup.php?debug=1 to see the detailed error messages and SQL queries.)
updating to version 1 (MySQL)...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS admin (
`username` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`password` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`created` datetime NOT NULL default '2000-01-01 00:00:00',
`modified` datetime NOT NULL default '2000-01-01 00:00:00',
`active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1',
PRIMARY KEY (`username`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM COMMENT='Postfix Admin - Virtual Admins';
```

DEBUG INFORMATION: Invalid query: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Check your error_log for the failed query.